# Calculating the probability that the demand will exceed what we have in stock

Tags: probability

You identified two products that have common average weekly demand, but  different standard deviations.

Product 1's weekly demand is distributed normally with a mean of 625 & standard deviation of 225.

Product 2's weekly demand is distributed normally with a mean of 630 & a standard deviation of 50.

If you stocked exactly the mean of these items, what is the probability that your demand will exceed what you have in stock?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: What if we stock more than the mean, say 20% above, how does that change the probability of either of the items being out of stock individually

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a random variable for the demand of Product 1 and $Y$ for the demand of Product 2.

$C \sim N(625,225^2)\\ Y\sim N(630,50^2)$

We want to find $P(X>625\cup Y>630)=P(X>625)+P(Y>630)-P(X>625\cap Y>630)=P(X>625)+P(Y>630)-P(X>625)P(Y>630)$

But $P(X>625) = P(Y>630) = \frac{1}{2}$ since, a Normal distribution has $\frac{1}{2}$ to be greater than its mean (as well as lower).

Therefore, the probability to find yourself with not enough stock (of either Product 1 or 2), is:

$P(X>625\cup Y>630)=\frac{3}{4}$

*As you saw, it's a rather simple calculation, but I made all the steps in case you think something in the question should change*

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I also wanted to know the probability of each item being out of stock individuality. How do I use the unit normal distribution table to answer this

Comment: The probability of a normal being higher than it's mean is $\frac{1}{2}$. I said so in the Answer.